# PDF openinng in new tab PHP mPDF

Tags: php, google-chrome, pdf, yii, http-headers

I had a problem with the fact that in the latest versions of Google Chrome removed the possibility of Top-frame navigation (as vulnerability [Description's here](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/GbVcuwg_QjM%5B101-125%5D)). I need to create a back-end PDF already with headers, etc and then open it in new browser tab. Which headers should I use correctly? As a library for the formation of the PDF document I use mPDF and YiiFramework.

```
$mPDF1 = Yii::app()->ePdf->mPDF('', 'A4', '8', '');
$mPDF1->WriteHTML($html_data);
$filename = 'pdf_' . time() . '.pdf';

$mPDF1->SetHeader(
    'Content-type: application/pdf',
    'Content-disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"',
    'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary',
    'Accept-Ranges: bytes'
);

echo $mPDF1->Output($filename, 'I');





if(objBrowse.appName == "Opera"){
    windowPrint = window.open('data:application/pdf;base64,'+data.content,  '_blank', 'width=800,height=600,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');

} else {
    //windowPrint = window.open('data:application/pdf;base64,'+data.content, '_blank');
    windowPrint = window.open(data.content, '_blank');
}
```

Comment: Isn't <a href="your-script-that-creates-the-pdf.php" target="_blank">...</a> what you are searching for?

Comment: I need it when the method finished (return or echo) -> and then avto open pdf in new tab. I mean that pdf file will be formed on fast.